# Globally unique message identifer for an Akka application

Tags: java, akka, uuid, akka-cluster

How can I construct a globally unique identifier on every message passed between actors in an Akka application? Note that my Akka application will eventually be running across multiple JVMs on a cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.util.UUID.randomUUID()` usually does the trick. Internally uses a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator `java.security.SecureRandom`.

Comment: I am currently using `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()` but I was hoping that there might be an alternative way of generating a UUID that might take advantage of the fact that Akka Actor paths are unique...

Comment: if your Akka actor paths are unique why not use the path as your identifier? otherwise java.util.UUID.randomUUID() would be the obvious way to go